# Is there a way to disable native image support in Micronaut?

Tags: intellij-idea, micronaut, graalvm-native-image

### My goal

I only want to run my Micronaut app in the JVM -- I have no interest in native image support. However, I can't find any documentation about how to turn it off.

### Why bother?

First, the native image support generates noise in my build output, like this:

```
> Configure project :service
[native-image-plugin] Instrumenting task with the native-image-agent: run
[native-image-plugin] Instrumenting task with the native-image-agent: runShadow
[native-image-plugin] Instrumenting task with the native-image-agent: test
[native-image-plugin] Instrumenting task with the native-image-agent: testNativeImage
```

Second, when I try to run a test in IntelliJ, it gives me this little menu, which means it takes one extra click to run the tests, which is annoying.

[image: testNativeImage menu screenshot]

### My ask

Is there some way to remove or disable native image support in Micronaut? Or is there some compelling reason why this is not possible or desirable?

Answer (score 2):

Have

```
plugins {
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.2"
    id("io.micronaut.minimal.application") version "3.5.1"
}
```

int your `build.gradle` (instead of io.micronaut.application). See also https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-gradle-plugin/latest/#_individual_plugins